# HBase table structure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

How to create a table structure in a **MySQL** database with reference from a column family based  **HBase** table?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi do want to create same table structure in MySql as u can do in Hbase or u want to import from Hbase table for which u are making MySql table.

Comment: Hello. Both are very different from each other. You can't use HBase like MySQL. Same holds true for table structure.

Comment: Hi Tariq & Piyush! I have HBase data exported to HDFS which I am trying to export to MySQL. When I am using Sqoop export, I would have to specify MySQL table to which HDFS will be exported to. I am not sure how to create a MySQL table structure that would fit HDFS data?

Comment: Hi tariq, i totally agree with u. But we can create same wide columnar structure in MySql as in Hbase. Only difference will be its rowkey and column family that we cannot have in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to import data from HBase to MySQL is using SQOOP  and you can go through this link http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase to understand how to do it.

> Each output column will be placed in the same column family, which
>   must be specified with --column-family. If the target table and column
>   family do not exist, the Sqoop job will exit with an error. You should
>   create the target table and column family before running an import.

Comment: I want to export HBase to MySQL. I tried to do it two steps - (1) exported HBase to HDFS (2) export HDFS to MySQL using Sqoop. I could do the step 1. I am stuck on step 2 as I am not sure how to create a table structure in MySQL that would fit an existing HDFS table?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Archer don't worry about the table structure. Try creating a table with same column names as in Hbase. Then use scoop command as:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name --table table_name  --export-dir /directory/where/your/file/located/in/HDFS --username username --password password -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001'
```

^A is a field delimiter and \n can be used as a row delimiter.
U can use other Input Parsing arguments based on ur requirement. Please let me know if that helps.